# VSCode language extension not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have created a new extension (tmlanguage) for VSCode using the Yeoman generator.
The extension where copied to users//.vscode/extensions.
This extenxion is working fine on two of my computers and one collegua's machine.
The extension is implemented, and i can see it in the extensions browser in VSCode.

When I added this for two other colleguas, the same way I did for the 3 first computers, it doesn't work. VSCode acts as if there is noe extensions to read, or does not read them at all. As if it does not check the extension folder.
I have tried to disable all extension, then enable them again, but still the same.
In the Extension browser there is no mentioning of the new extension.

Have tried restarting VSCode.
One of the machines is Win 11, but the other is Win 10. The machines that work are all Win 10, not that I think this has something to do with it.
All running latest version of VSCode.

Is there a way to force VSCode to recognize the extensions?
Have anybody experienced similar things?

Comment: Please learn to use `vsce package` to generate the right package for deployment. Copying folders over won't work if the actual extension folder by VS Code is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Lex Li for pointing me in the correct direction. I thought I had followed the correct way to do this, to just copy the extension to the .vscode\extensions folder, as specified in several tutorials.

But using the vsce to generate a .vsix file did work.